# How to write Japanese double-consonant pattern in Windows Occidental keyboard

Tags: keyboard, language, input, japanese

I'm learning Hiragana, and recently I've learned about double consonants. As an example I saw `きつさてん` - kissaten-, that means `Cafe`.

My question basically is how to write it in a computer: I can put my keyboard in Hiragana mode and go through all the syllables, but I don't know how to write the appropriate `つ` in "lowercase" in the middle to create the double-consonant pattern.

I'm aware that it may be a highly dependent thing on the keyboard configuration and operative system and so forth, but my case is a Windows PC with the input set to Japanese and Hiragana mode.

As far as I know, all the things that I'm typing in this mode are being written in uppercase, so when I try to tape `きつさてん` I'm not writing it actually, since the only way for me to write `つ` is the uppercase (typing actually `tsu` in my occidental keyboard).

Thanks in advance

*Disclaimer*: I was going to post it in [Japanese Stackexchange](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/), but when I was about to publish it tagged as `computing` the description made me post it here:

> Questions about the Japanese language used in the context of computing.
> Questions about technical support (e.g. "How do I input Japanese characters?") belong on Super User.

Comment: Does [How can I type special kana letters? – iKnow! Support](https://support.iknow.jp/hc/en-us/articles/206400541-How-can-I-type-special-kana-letters-) answer your question? It seems you have to type the first part of the next letter twice.

Comment: [How can I type special kana letters? – iKnow! Support](https://support.iknow.jp/hc/en-us/articles/206400541-How-can-I-type-special-kana-letters-)

Comment: Yes! It does! It's as they say there, typing twice the next consonant, `tt` in my example case!

Comment: Feel free to write a self answer to your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in [iKnow Support](https://support.iknow.jp/hc/en-us/articles/206400541-How-can-I-type-special-kana-letters-) link provided by [davidpostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill), where they address this and other issues when writing Kana with occidental keyboards:

To produce a double-consonant pattern you only need to **type twice the consonant and then continue with your regular writing**, being the second consonant already the first element of the next syllable. Therefore, writing `ssa` would produce the expect lowercase `っ` and `っさ` as a whole.

I completely encourage to take a full view of the previous link if you came here looking for this issue, since it has further information that will be extremely useful to type correctly Kana.